# Format a number with thousands separators in shell/awk

Tags: awk, sh

```
awk -F, '
{ 
   printf("    Code %s  %s\n",$1,$2)
   r[NR] = $1
   c[NR] = $3
}

END { for(i = 1; i <= NR; i++) printf("  %s Record Count   %s\n", r[i],c[i])

}' totalsum.txt
```

this is my input file

```
17,123456,1
16,1234,2
0211,34567,2
21,2345,2
```

am getting output like below.,

```
Code   17  123456
Code   16  1234
Code 0211  34567
Code   21  2345
17 Record Count   1
16 Record Count   2
0211  Record Count  2
21 Record Count   2
```

I need format the output like.,below representing the values with ,

```
Code   16  1,234
Code 0211  34,567
Code   21  112,345
17 Record Count   1
16 Record Count   2
0211  Record Count  2
21 Record Count   2
```

could some one please help me.

Comment: Your sample input does not match your output. Please fix this

Comment: No, you're not getting that output from that input. Come on - a TINY bit of effort into forming the question please...

Comment: I have never seen thousands split like `1,12,345` before...

Comment: It looks vaguely like [Indian numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Numbering_System)?

Comment: agree JD., my mistake.. it should be in us style formatting 112,345 only.

Comment: hi freiends.. am trying to route the value to file.. print("\n\n Tran Code %s  %\047.2f\n",$1,$2) >> $FILENAME but its not writting to file ..any mistake in syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `%'d` instead of `%s` as the format specifier if you want thousands separators.  Since you're passing the awk script on the command line, getting the quotes right can be tricky.  With a hat tip to [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton), here's one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -F, '
{ 
   printf("    Code %s  %\047d\n",$1,$2)
   r[NR] = $1
   c[NR] = $3
}

END { for(i = 1; i <= NR; i++) printf("  %s Record Count   %s\n", r[i],c[i])

}' totalsum.txt
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh
    Code 37  123,456
    Code 27  1,234
    Code 0367  34,567
    Code 41  2,345
  37 Record Count   1
  27 Record Count   2
  0367 Record Count   2
  41 Record Count   2
```

Comment: For simplicity in quoting, always just use `\047` to get a `'` inside a `'`-delimited awk script. Also note that this will only work in some locales, e.g. it will work with `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` but will not work with `LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: hi i have used "f" instead of "d"... am looking for output 123,456.12.. after demical 2 precision... i have used 2f but it doesnt support..could u help

Comment: hi rob.. one more help.. am trying to sort the data before i process.. i have given like this sort -t "," -k1,1 totalsum.txt.. but not worked,.. could u correct me

Comment: You should post a new question for that.